# What is $F_P$ and $E(P)$?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, optimization, network-flow

I'm reading *Handbook of Graph Theory*:

> [image]

At this section, he speaks about $F_P$ and $E(P)$. It's not really clear what they are. I guess there is  enough context for someone to answer me but if you need more context, just tell me.

Comment: $E(P)$ are the edges of $P$. I do not see any mention of $F_P$, but $f_P$ is clearly defined.